# Updating my ObservableCollection on a worker thread still hangs my UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, ui-thread

I have a log window in my application, when I have a few thousand logs, filtering them to include or exclude different log levels makes the UI unresponsive for a period of time from the work load. So I have tried to move the heavy lifting to a worker thread, and am having the same issue still.

I am using an `ObservableCollection` to hold the log information in my model, and I just reference that directly with my ViewModel. I have used `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization()` to let my worker thread update my observable collection without Dispatching it to the UI thread.

I run the following to update the collection on a worker thread with a

```
Task.Run(new Action(() => FilterList()));
```

Methods:

```
    private void FilterList()
    {
        //Necessary even with EnableCollectionSynchronization
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            FilteredLogEvents.Clear();
        }));

        foreach (LogEvent log in FilterLogEvents())
        {
            FilteredLogEvents.Add(log);
        }

        RaisePropertyChanged("FilteredLogEvents");
        FinishedFilteringLogs();
    }

    //Filters and returns a list of filtered log events
    private List<LogEvent> FilterLogEvents()
    {
        List<LogEvent> selectedEvents = (from x in LogEvents
                                         where ((ViewDebugLogs == true) ? x.Level == "Debug" : false)
                                         || ((ViewErrorLogs == true) ? x.Level == "Error" : false)
                                         || ((ViewInfoLogs == true) ? x.Level == "Info" : false)
                                         select x).ToList();
        return selectedEvents;
    }
```

This causes the UI to freeze on the `foreach`. I also tried just newing up an `ObservableCollection` and then assigning `FilteredLogEvents` to it with `FilteredLogEvents = myNewCollection;` this also causes the UI to freeze for a short while during that process.

If I use `Thread.Sleep(1)` within the `foreach` loop the UI remains responsive, though this seems like an inelegant and hacky solution.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Edit: A bit more code context from this class (`LogEntries`)
The callback for `FinishedFilteringLogsEventHandler` goes back to the ViewModel to change a bool that enables a couple checkboxes when the filtering is complete.

```
    //Constructor
    public LogEntries()
    {
        foreach(NlogViewerTarget target in NLog.LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets.Where(t=>t is NlogViewerTarget).Cast<NlogViewerTarget>())
        {
            target.RecieveLog += RecieveLog;
        }

        FilteredLogEvents = new ObservableCollection<LogEvent>();
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(FilteredLogEvents, filteredLogEventsLock);
    }

    public delegate void FinishedFilteringLogsEvent();
    public FinishedFilteringLogsEvent FinishedFilteringLogsEventHandler;

    private object filteredLogEventsLock = new object();

    public ObservableCollection<LogEvent> FilteredLogEvents { get; set; }
```

Comment: 1) You're not waiting for the collection to be cleared - `BeginInvoke` is probably a bad idea. 2) You're not showing your synchronization callback for the collection - that quite likely has something to do with your problem. In any case, the most immediate problem is IMO that you're adding one item after another, rather than adding the whole list at once, which causes synchronization with the UI on every single `Add`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Luaan, the callback goes to the ViewModel to re-enabled some checkboxes once the filtering is complete, it also contains a `RaisePropertyChanged()` for the VM from when I was trying to just update the entire list at once. When updating the entire list at once, either by using `FilteredLogEvents = new ObservableCollection(FilterLogEvents())` or creating a new collection and assigning it with `FilteredLogEvents = myNewCollection` the UI also hangs in the same manner. For the `BeginInvoke` I have to dispatch the `Clear`, I will change that to `Invoke`

Comment: Well, the UI thread will always have to do all the binding - and that's always going to hang the UI. The only way around it is to use some virtual binding mechanism. `EnableCollectionSynchronization` does one and only thing - makes all the notifications synchronized with any changes from different threads; it doesn't do anything to improve performance or such. You can use the synchronous `Invoke` instead of the asynchronous `BeginInvoke` to wait for the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts to consider to improve the speed and responsiveness of your code

A few days ago I asked a similar question and someone advised me not to use the threadpool for long running Tasks. The thread pool is a collection of available threads, that can be started swiftly in comparison to starting a traditional thread like System.ComponentModel.BackGroundWorker.

Although it takes more time to create and start a real thread, this is no problem for long running tasks.

The number of threads in the thread pool is limited, so better not use it for longer running tasks.

If you run a task, it is only scheduled to run in the near future when a thread is available. If all threads are busy it will take some time before the thread starts.

The change from Task to Backgroundworker is limited. If you really want to stick to tasks, consider creating an async function:

```
async void FilteredLogEvents.AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<LogEvent> logEvents)
```

or maybe better:

```
async void FilteredLogEvents.SetAsync(IEnumerable<LogEvent> logEvents)
```

which does the clear and add in one async call.

Make your own function async:

```
private async void FilterList()
{
    var filteredLogEvents = FilterLogEvents();
    var myTask = Task.Run( () => FilteredLogEvents.SetAsync(filteredLogEvents);
    // if desired do other things.
    // wait until ready:
    await myTask();
    RaisePropertyChanged("FilteredLogEvents");
    FinishedFilteringLogs();
}
```

By the way: Are you sure that your sequence of logEvents does not change while you are filtering it?

- If so, why do you use ToList() instead of returning an IEnumerable and use deferred execution?
- If you are not certain: what happens if during the FilterLogEvents your sequence of logEvents changes?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I really don't know why I used `ToList()` other than it suited my needs. If a log is added while filtering I get an `.InvalidOperationException`. I went ahead and removed to `ToList`and just returned an `IEnumerable`, I still get the same error anyways, looks like I need to fix that as well `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`. Besides that, the UI still hangs regardless of how I thread the filtering,  Luaan's analysis makes sense, that the UI has to handle the binding which is probably the cause.